# Yii2 behavior : Dynamically attribute set value

Tags: php, yii2

**UPDATE**

I have a record that I have inserted using Yii
My Model named is `Shipment` that implemented :

```
 /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            ],
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Suppose those are records in the database like this:

```
DATABASE (1:1)
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------------+------------+
| id | freight_created_at | freight_updated_at | created_at | updated_at |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------------+------------+
| XX | NULL               | NULL               | 1597223608 | 1597315472 |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------------+------------+
```

Then I need to update another column called `freight_created_at` & `freight_updated_at` . It's because in same record, so I cannot using EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT again.

My action for PUT freight, The goal is:

1. If column `freight_created_at` is empty, fill in `freight_created_at` and `freight_updated_at`
2. Others update `freight_updated_at` only

Then in Yii2

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function actionPutFreightDitawarkan($id) {
   $model = $this->findModel($id);
   $model->scenario = Shipment::SCENARIO_FREIGHT_DITAWARKAN;
   $model->attachBehaviors([FreightDitawarkanTimestamp::class]);
   
   ... 

}
```

If I want to use a behavior, how do I implement it? So far, the behavior looked like this.

**BEHAVIOR**

```
class FreightDitawarkanTimestamp extends AttributeBehavior {

    public $createdAtAttribute = 'freight_created_at';
    public $updatedAtAttribute = 'freight_updated_at';
    public $value;

    public function init() {
        if (empty($this->attributes)) {
            $this->attributes = [
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE =>
                    [
                        $this->createdAtAttribute,
                        $this->updatedAtAttribute
                    ]
            ];
        }
        parent::init();

    }
    protected function getValue($event) {
        $this->value = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        return parent::getValue($event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior suits here only if you want to use it in more than one model, otherwise you could just use `$model->touch()` (i.e. `$model->touch('freight_created_at')`) because you have access to that method through already attached TimestampBehavior.

But if this is the multimodel case indeed your approach is good. I would override the `evaluateAttributes()` as well to meet you requirements like:

```
public function evaluateAttributes($event)
{
    if ($this->skipUpdateOnClean
        && $event->name == ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE
        && empty($this->owner->dirtyAttributes)
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if (!empty($this->attributes[$event->name])) {
        $attributes = (array) $this->attributes[$event->name];
        $value = $this->getValue($event);
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute === $this->createdAtAttribute && !empty($this->owner->$attribute)) {
                // don't update "created_at" value if already set
                continue;
            }
            $this->owner->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

And `getValue()` can be simplified to:

```
protected function getValue($event)
{
    return date('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```